# Need help regenerating images after image cache flush

Tags: 8, theming, media

TL;DR - Flushed image cache for an image style that is used in basically every blog. They are not regenerating on page load. They regenerate when i edit and save the node. Looking for ways to programmatically edit/save all the nodes.

Hello all,

As mentioned above i am trying to find a way to programmatically re-save nodes, or at least run the process that regenerates an image.

I recently did an image cache flush. In most cases this would be no problem. Image styles are re-generated on page load. Except, it seems, in my niche case.

I use the [Insert Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert) for my writers to insert images into their articles. This is where i believe things are going wrong. The images aren't being regenerated unless you go into the node edit screen. Note: i just realized you don't have to save the node for the image reload to work, simply going to the edit page.

I have tried using the built in 'save many' functionality built into views. However, re saving the node this way doesn't solve the problem.

I also tried a module called 'Resave all nodes' and ultimately this didn't work either. Note: all this module essentially does is call $node::load(x); $node->save(); in batches.

So there must be some hook that is run once the edit page is opened. Is there a way to run all those processes without going to the edit page? Is there a way to see all the hooks being run once the edit page is opened?

My first solution is always brute-force. In this case i would use puppeteer or selinium and 'manually' go to the edit pages. I don't even have to let the page fully load. it seems i just need to an authorized request to the edit page and the image is reloaded.

But there must be a better way. Can anyone offer me some insight please?

Edit: To be clear, my setup uses the insert module linked above to insert images into article body fields. Images are hosted on s3

Comment: That's interesting. What happens if you get one of the image URLs from inspecting the page and visit the URL directly?

Comment: Usually all you have to do to regenerate image styles is to visit the node (non-edit) page, so it's as simple as using wget to pull all the pages on your site.  So there must be something unusual about your setup that is preventing that.

Comment: @sonfd I just clarified in my original post. But i host my images on s3 using the s3fs module. so i get a 403 error because the image has not been regenerated.

Comment: @PatrickKenny Agreed. However, i assume that my combination of the insert module and using s3fs as my file system for image/file hosting is to be blamed. Maybe just the insert module, as all the other images regenerated just fine. So i suppose my question still stands. Is there a way to run the hooks that are executed on the edit screen programmatically?

Comment: Have you cleared cache(s)?

Comment: I created https://www.drupal.org/project/resave_all_nodes somewhen in the past. You can select a node type and then resave all nodes of that type in a batch. Might be of help?

Comment: Wow, didn't know 5 months ago this has been added to Drush 11: `drush entity:save node --bundle=article` to re-save all nodes of type article.

Comment: Image variant generation is an automatic process on page load. Is the web server nginx?